# How to change the dataset to the format of Progenetix Informative matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst

I have a fMRI data matrix `A`, the size of which is `500*3000 double`. Here `500` represents the number of observations, `3000` represents the number of voxels.

And I have another label matrix `B` corresponding matrix `A`, the size of which is `500*1` double. The values in matrix `B` is from `1` to `4`, which represents `4` categories.

I want to change the matrix `A` combined with matrix `B` to the format of Progenetix Informative matrix by using Matlab (if it is possible).

Can anyone give me a help?